# noexcept specifying conditions under which function does not throw

Tags: c++, c++11, noexcept, gcc4.7

I am having some trouble wrapping my head around noexcept.

```
template <int SIZE>
int pop(int idx) noexcept(noexcept(SIZE > 0)) // this is what I dont understand
{
  if (idx <= 0)
    throw std::out_of_range("My array doesnt go that high");
  return idx;
}
```

This is just a simple function, but you see how it only throws an exception when idx <= 0, I dont understand. So in my specification, noexcept(idx > 0), I am trying to tell the compilier this function ONLY throws no exceptions if idx > 0. Am I doing this right?

Any help is appreciated, I hope I am explaining it right. Just some simple explanation would be great.

Comment: In case anyone else has same problem, K-ballo response helped, and also, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec really helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the `noexept` *specification* expects a *constant expression*, not a runtime expression. You have used the `noexcept` *specificatiom* together with the `noexcept` *operator*. `noexcept(idx >0)` returns `true` as comparing two integers does not throw, and you are using that `true` as the argument to the `noexcept` *specification* telling the compiler your function never throws. The declaration

```
int pop(int idx) noexcept(noexcept(idx > 0))
```

says this function does not throw as long as `idx > 0` does not throw, which is *always* the case for an `int`.

**Update:** Now you've changed the code in the question so that `idx` is a *non-type template argument*, however the same reasoning applies. Comparing `int`s **never throws**.

What you seem to be trying to do cannot be done in *C++*. That is, specify whether a function throws or not based on its runtime arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think you know what I am talking about though. Can you post an agreeable example?

Comment: @bryan sammon: What you seem to be trying to do cannot be done in _C++_. That is, specify whether a function throws or not based on its runtime arguments.

Comment: Actually its all just new to me, just trying to learn noexcept specifications. Even if it is a compile time constant. I just put that example there to have a example.

Comment: @bryan sammon: The `noexcept` _operator_ returns `false` if any of the operations could throw, it does not consider the values of the arguments themselves but only each of the functions/expressions involved. The `noexcept` _specification_ with a `true` argument indicates that a function does not throw.

Comment: well said, now that is what I was looking for, thanks alot man